# Jira Xray JQL - All test executions for a testplan

Tags: jira, jql, jira-xray

How would I construct a JQL query to find all text executions for a given testplan? I do have the testplan key.

I know this sounds strange since you can see it, when you open the testplan. But I am trying to automate the creation of executions and in the API the testplan issue has no link to it's executions, it's only the other way around. So I try to get them by query.

Comment: Are you using xray on jira datacenter or on jira cloud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
issue in testPlanTestExecutions("XXX")
```

XXX = test plan key

Comment: Is there any way to do it in Cloud version? It does not have testPlanTestExecutions